# Structure and fflush(stdin)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Person{
    char codeChacter[20];
    char fullName[30];
    int Iq, Eq;
};

int main(){
    struct Person cha1, cha2;

    printf("Enter detail of character 1: \n");
    printf("code Character: ");
    gets(cha1.codeChacter);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Full Name: ");
    gets(cha1.fullName);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter Iq and Eq: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &cha1.Iq, &cha1.Eq);

    printf("Enter detail of character 2: \n");
    printf("code Character: ");
    gets(cha2.codeChacter);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Full Name: ");
    gets(cha2.fullName);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter Iq and Eq: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &cha2.Iq, &cha2.Eq);

    printf("\n---------------------Detail------------------\n");
    printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\n", cha1.codeChacter, cha1.fullName, cha1.Iq, cha1.Eq);
    printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\n", cha2.codeChacter, cha2.fullName, cha2.Iq, cha2.Eq);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my first program in structure. When I run this application, it work but it not right with my mind. So can you help me change my fail? Thanks very much!

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: `gets()` is bad, use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: BTW, what is your expected behav and what did you get?

Comment: Your problems are `fflush(stdin)` and `gets`, otherwise its a simple program .

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @SouravGhosh When I delete statement fflush(stdin) it still not work right.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I trying to get some information from user. Example: name

Comment: Note - under Visual Studio, `fflush(stdin)` *will* clear the input buffer.  However, that's pretty much the *only* implementation that guarantees such behavior, and as a rule it shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%d%d", (pointers to read));` won't remove the newline character from the input stream, then the `gets` will read the newline character and won't work as "expected".

- don't use `fflush(stdin);`, which is undefined behavior.
- don't use `gets()`, which has risk of buffer overrun.

Possible fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Person{
    char codeChacter[20];
    char fullName[30];
    int Iq, Eq;
};

char* read_line(char *out, size_t bufsize){
    char *lf;
    if (fgets(out, bufsize, stdin) == NULL) return NULL;
    /* remove the newline character because fgets store it while gets donesn't */
    for (lf = out; *lf != '\0'; lf++){
        if (*lf == '\n'){
            *lf = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    return out;
}

int main(void){
    char read_buf[1024];
    struct Person cha1, cha2;

    printf("Enter detail of character 1: \n");
    printf("code Character: ");
    read_line(cha1.codeChacter, sizeof(cha1.codeChacter));
    printf("Full Name: ");
    read_line(cha1.fullName, sizeof(cha1.fullName));
    printf("Enter Iq and Eq: ");
    read_line(read_buf, sizeof(read_buf));
    sscanf(read_buf, "%d%d", &cha1.Iq, &cha1.Eq);

    printf("Enter detail of character 2: \n");
    printf("code Character: ");
    read_line(cha2.codeChacter, sizeof(cha2.codeChacter));
    printf("Full Name: ");
    read_line(cha2.fullName, sizeof(cha2.fullName));
    printf("Enter Iq and Eq: ");
    read_line(read_buf, sizeof(read_buf));
    sscanf(read_buf, "%d%d", &cha2.Iq, &cha2.Eq);

    printf("\n---------------------Detail------------------\n");
    printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\n", cha1.codeChacter, cha1.fullName, cha1.Iq, cha1.Eq);
    printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\n", cha2.codeChacter, cha2.fullName, cha2.Iq, cha2.Eq);
    return 0;
}
```

Using this code, you have to enter Iq and Eq in the same line and you can't insert any blank line before inputting Iq and Eq, while the program using `scanf` won't require that.